# How to check bounding box in XNA 4.0?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, collision, bounding-box

I want to use class BoundingBox in XNA 4.0 to check collision between  cube with cube or cube with sphere? I know about BoundingSphere but I don't know use to BoundingBox. Have any good sample about this! Thanks!

Comment: A good way to find information about XNA classes is to google them, or visit http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb196942.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You make boundingboxes like this:

```
Vector3 CenterOfBox = new Vector3(10,10,10);
int Width = 10;
int Height = 10;
BoundingBox BoundingBox1 = new BoundingBox(CenterOfBox - new Vector(Width/2,Height/2,Width/2),CenterOfBox + new Vector(Width/2,Height/2,Width/2));
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingbox.boundingbox.aspx

Lets say you have BoundingBox1 and BoundingBox2

Then you can check if they intersect with:

```
if(BoundingBox1.Intersect(BoundingBox2))
{
    //They hit
}
else
{
    //They don't hit
}
```

You can also pass a BoundingSphere in the Intersect function

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingbox.intersects.aspx

Comment: Thanks you! And you know how to check BoundingSphere for one ModelBone??

Comment: @Google New  The ModelBone don't have an bounding, it is a holder for a position. You should get it's ModelMesh to calculate the boundingsphere, ModelMeshes have the property "BoundingSphere" (or you can make a sphere at the bone's position)

Comment: @GoogleNew You should look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb197344.aspx